# Using quadrature encoder with STM32 MCU

Tags: stm32, embedded

I am trying to use a [quadrature encoder](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10982) with my NUCLEO-F303K8 board (see code below) and it is working ok but not perfect. I connected the encoder according to fig 4. in the [datasheet](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/Switches/EC12PLRGBSDVBF-D-25K-24-24C-6108-6HSPEC.pdf) (I didn't have any 0.01uF capacitors so I used 0.1uF instead). I noticed that occasionally the counter is incremented twice when I rotate the encoder one step. When I modify the prescaler value I noticed that the counter behavior changes a lot. For example a prescaler value of 11 requires that I rotate the encoder 6 steps in order to increment the counter once; the opposite behavior can be seen with a very small prescaler value. Using trial and error I have determined that a prescaler value of 3 works the best.

I am new to encoders and feel like I am doing a lot of guessing here and could use some assistance. Can you see anything in the datasheet that suggest what prescaler value I should use? There is some timing mentioned but I don't know what to do with it. The system core clock is running at 72MHz. Or is there something strange in the code below or something in the way I have connected the encoder I could change?

EDIT:

I connected the encoder to an oscilloscope (measuring at the input pins of the NUCLEO board) and rotated the encoder clockwise; these are the results.

With the capacitors (0.1uF):
[image: With capacitors]

Without capacitors:
[image: Without capacitors]

To me it looks much better without capacitors but in reality when I rotate the encoder it works very poorly without capacitors. Can anyone explain these results it appears strange to an amateur like me.

EDIT2:

I changed the timebase as suggested and now I see the bouncing of the signal. From my observations today it seems worse after the falling edge compared to the rising edge for some reason.

Without capacitors:
[image: Without capacitors]

Most of the time it looks good with capacitors but sometimes it looks like this or slightly worse:
[image: With capacitors]

I bought more capacitors today and tested 0.01uF, 0.022uF and 0.047uF. I would say I got the best results when I used the bigger ones, i.e. 0.047uF and 0.1uF. The rise and fall times are slower but it doesn't seem to have a negative effect and they give a cleaner signal. Is it correct that the rise/fall times can be decreased by choosing smaller resistors? What other effects would it have?

Code I am using:

```
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_TIM1, ENABLE);
RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA | RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOB, ENABLE);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =  GPIO_Pin_8 | GPIO_Pin_9;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource8, GPIO_AF_6);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource9, GPIO_AF_6);

NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM1_UP_TIM16_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

PrescalerValue = (uint16_t) ((SystemCoreClock ) / 18000000) - 1; // Prescaler is 3

TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 6;
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 0;
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = 0;
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;

TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM1, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure);

TIM_PrescalerConfig(TIM1, PrescalerValue, TIM_PSCReloadMode_Immediate);

TIM_EncoderInterfaceConfig(TIM1, TIM_EncoderMode_TI12, TIM_ICPolarity_Rising, TIM_ICPolarity_Rising);

TIM_ITConfig(TIM1, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);

TIM_Cmd(TIM1, ENABLE);

uint32_t counter = 0;

for(;;)
{
    counter = TIM_GetCounter(TIM1);

    // ...use the value...
}
```

Comment: might really just be the oversized cap; your RC low pass will simply have a different impulse response.

Comment: RC time constant is 1ms, so 100 steps per seconds should be easily resolvable.

Comment: Be sure that the encoder's output is exactly what you expect.  The linked description says "similar to" Gray code.  Take a look at the datasheet and confirm that the waveforms (especially the phase of the waveforms) is what your decoder needs.  I've been hit by this before (though not with your board), and had to resort to decoding 'manually' in the ISR code.  -Chris

Comment: It also looks like a mechanical encoder (not optical).  De-bouncing on the inputs is a really, really good idea.  Just adding a cap may not be adequate.  Fire up an oscilloscope, and look at the transitions.  Also, I've seen mechanical switches play havoc with uC interrupt inputs.  Consider a healthy, and robust, de-bouncing strategy.

Comment: I don't think you can use a prescaler with a bi-directional counter, you're probably going to have to scale the result using software.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen I hooked it up to an oscilloscope, thoughts on the results (see edit)?

Comment: Just one capacitor (and clearly oversized) for de-bouncing circuit is not enough, check other reference circuits - it has also 2 resistors. But even with the correct circuit you will get sometimes extra shot (at least on my cheap noname encoders), so software de-boundcing is also must be implemented. I use edge interrupts - in the handler I save the timestamp (use HAL_GetTick) and check against last recorded timestamp. If interval is within say 100ms, then I ignore the last one. BTW in the handler you shall also detect the direction of rotation by reading the state of other pin.

Comment: @dbostream See Jack's comment in regard to the scope's timebase setting.  However, perhaps you could consider avoiding all of this mechanical-encoder business, and change the encoder to an optical type?  I believe that you will end up with an easier system to program for, it will be more reliable, and longer lived.  You can even get optical encoders with built-in Schmitt trigger outputs.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Thanks for the suggestions, I like the fact that it has a built in button and RGB LED, are there optical ones with these features too? Btw I have added pictures now with a changed timebase.

Comment: @Flanker Got any suggestion on a better debouncing circuit? I got better results with a big capacitor than the suggested 0.01nF one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoder you are using is a simple mechanical wiper, it's almost impossible to debounce them with a simple RC circuit alone as shown in the datasheet.

The capacitor you used is too big with delays out above 1 mS, the suggested 0.01 uF will give about 0.1 mS delay on a rising pulse and somewhat longer on a negative change. Neither value however will stop switch bounce affecting your count since the wiper is not itself a detent in this type of switch (in any I've worked with), the detents are a simple external shaft position detent.

Internally they will look like this (or some similar physical layout):
[image]

One way I've handled these mechanical encoders in the past is to use a timer tick (1 kHz or so interrupt is usually readily available) to read the A/B values into a temporary 8 bit register and set my program accessible copy of A/B values only when there are 4 '1' bits accumulated for each of A/B.
This ensures values are not made program accessible unless there has been no change in A/B state for at least 4 mS. You can obviously change the tick to get any debounce value you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I connected the encoder to an oscilloscope (see my edit) any thoughts about the results?

Comment: @dbostream You need to set your timebase in the uS region to see the switch bounce. Digital scopes have a wonderful way of cleaning up your view of signals.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the wrong timebase, I have uploaded new pictures now that show some bouncing.

Comment: @dbostream As you can now see "switch bounce" is a loose description. The fact is that as the wiper lifts up onto the PC track, this is where you get a poor connection. You also see that the wiper does not make a perfect connection as it's dragged across the PC substrate, so the 'bounce can occur anywhere during movement when the wiper is on the PC (low A/B) ....but of course occurs nowhere where there is no PC track. Hence the algorithm I use in the answer above. It has served me well in the past for both point contact (spring bounce) and wiping contacts.

Comment: Ok I will accept your answer. If I come to the conclusion, after using the encoder some more, that the double counting occurs too often I will try to implement debouncing as you have described.

Answer (score 1):

I would use (along with smaller debounce capacitors) a Schmidt trigger circuit to connect with the counters on each leg A and B. It will remove the pesky noise without crazy amounts of capacitance. Start with a 74HC14 as an example. These are inverting buffers with hysteresis. Nothing changes until the threshold is reached- then zap - it changes state. The beauty is that in the reverse direction, the threshold is different. That means there is no dithering about the threshold value because it changes depending on the direction of the change of state.